# Receive email on 2 email providers

Tags: email, google-workspace, outlook.com

Is there a possibility to receive emails on 2 different email providers?

I’ll describe my issue very clearly: I have a small company and I have an old Outlook.com account where I can receive emails like `@yourdomain.com`.

I want to migrate to Google apps, but I have a problem because Google apps don’t work in China so I want to keep the old Outlook.com account and receive all email also there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.   You need to get your mail provider to forward a copy of emails to both Gmail and Outlook.com.